# Microsoft Сертификация программы для организации

Tags: windows, сертификат

Есть организация которая занимается разработкой программного обеспечения под Desktop Windows. Microsoft о организации-издателе ничего не знает. Организация-издатель (юридическое лицо) не платит за услуги транзакцией с банковской карты как физическое лицо, а платит по  выставленому счёту. Нужно чтобы Windows знал о программном обеспечении, а не втирал о неизвестном издателе, ПЗ.  Как и где зарегистрировать издателя? Как сертифицировать программное обеспечение?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [UAC: как сделать доверенное приложение? Убрать строку "Неизвестно" в поле "Издатель" при появлении окна безопасности UAC (сертификация приложения)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/9054f2f2-dc24-451f-831b-9928f138feec/uac-?forum=winstoreappsru)

Comment: @Grundy читал уже, проще создать учетную запись розработчика на мой взгляд, но вот я не нашел выставление счета..(

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Издатель WPF-приложения в окне RunAs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906986/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-wpf-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5-runas)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо купить сертификат у так называемого Certificate Authority. Их несколько разных, хотя в случае оплаты безналом выбор сильно сужается. Наберите в поисковике "*code signing сертификат*" и будет вам большой список предложений.

Имейте в виду, что покупать нужно именно "сертификат для подписи кода". Цены у разных CA очень разнятся, хотя продают одно и то же, так что не спешите покупать у первого попавшегося, походите по рынку.

Еще один момент - сертификат нужно покупать каждый год. Можно купить сразу на два или три года, но по деньгам будет одно и то же.