# Издатель WPF-приложения в окне RunAs

Tags: wpf, windows, uac

Подскажите, как указать издателя для WPF-приложения в окне запроса UAC ?

Окно, что появляется при запуске приложения от имени администратора (runas).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это подпись, сертификат. Он покупается.

Comment: Только покупается? Можно ли сформировать какой-то свой, локальный?

Comment: Подписать то можно, но не видел что бы винда его отображала там...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создать свой сертификат с помощью [makecert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/makecert)

Открываем командную строку Visual Studio, выполняем команду такого вида

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Vasya Pupkin Software" -b 01/01/2018 -e 01/01/2028 -sky exchange -ss my
```

Сертификат появится в хранилище текущего пользователя. Открываем mmc, выполняем "Файл - Добавить или удалить оснастку", выбираем "Сертификаты". Находим созданный сертификат, делаем экспорт, выбрав в мастере параметры "Экспортировать закрытый ключ", "Экспортировать все расширенные свойства", и указав формат pfx для выходного файла. В итоге получаем файл .pfx с сертификатом и закрытым ключом, который можно использовать для подписания приложений.

Повторно сделаем экспорт, отказавшись на этот раз от экспорта закрытого ключа и выбрав формат cer. Получим в результате файл сертификата без закрытого ключа, который понадобится для распространения на целевые машины.

2. Подписать программу с помощью [Signtool](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)

В командной строке Visual Studio выполняем

```
signtool sign /f "(путь к pfx)" /p (пароль закрытого ключа) /v "(путь к exe)"
```

Получаем подписанный exe-файл.

3. На машинах, где будет запускаться программа, добавить сертификат (без закрытого ключа) в хранилище "Доверенные корневые центры сертификации".

Для этого в оснастке "Сертификаты" выбираем хранилище, выполняем "Действия" - "Все задачи" - "Импорт" и указываем cer-файл.

Должно получиться так:

[image: certificate]

**Примечание.** Если вам нужно, чтобы сертификат работал на всех машинах, он должен быть выдан нормальным центром сертификации.

Результат:

[image: UAC]